# Detect when the last item in an array has come to a stop

Tags: actionscript-3, algorithm

I've got an array of sprites which I'm animating by incrementing their rotationX property. What I want is for them all to disappear once the **last** item in the array has come full circle. The problem is that their rotation speeds are being generated by a randomized function, so I can't just go to the end of the array to find the last one. Each time it will be a different one.

So I have an array of Sprites:

```
for(var i:int=0; i<arrSprites.length; i++)
{
    addChild(arrSprites[i]) ;   
}
```

Then I have my event listener:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
```

And my handler:

```
private function loop(e:Event):void
{
    for(var i:int=0; i<arrSprites.length; i++)
    {
        var currentSprite:Sprite = arrSprites[i];
        if(currentSprite.rotationX < 361) //this will detect the first one 
                                                      //to finish but I want the last 
            {
                currentSprite.rotationX += arrSprites[i].speed; //random speed
            }
            else
            {
                deleteTheSprites(); //removes all sprites and does other stuff
            }


        }
    }
```

There's got to be an elegant way to do this. Anyone know what it is?

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private function loop(e:Event):void
{
    var finished : int = 0; // will count the number of sprites finished
    for each (var current:Sprite in arrSprites)
    {
        if (current.rotationX < 361) current.rotationX += current.speed;
        else if (++finished == arrSprites.length) deleteTheSprites();  // executes only if all sprites have finished
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant and yes, elegant. Thanks.